# Find all nodes from an XML using cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, search, celementtree

Is there a way to find all nodes in a xml tree using cElementTree? The findall method works only for specified tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XPath paths](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm) on the findall method:

> The 1.2 release supports simple
>   element location paths. In its
>   simplest form, a location path is one
>   or more tag names, separated by
>   slashes (/).
>
> You can also use an asterisk (*)
>   instead of a tag name, to match all
>   elements at that level. For example,
>   */subtag returns all subtag grandchildren.
>
> An empty tag (//) is used to search on
>   all levels of the tree, beneath the
>   current level. The empty tag must
>   always be followed by a tag name or an
>   asterisk.

```
etree.findall('.//*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at node.getiterator()?